# React native moment formatted date in invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, momentjs

I have the following code in my RN application.

```
  getFormattedDate = (date) => {
    const formattedDate = moment(new Date(date)).format('MMMM, DD YYYY');
    return { date: formattedDate };
  }
```

When I run this on the emulator, the formatted date is displayed properly. But when I run this on device, it says, invalid date. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How does `date` look like? Is it an ISO date string?

Comment: This is the format. => June, 20 2019

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comments, I assume that the `date` parameter is a string. If you want to create a new moment from a string, you have to pass the date format. The newly created moment can then be formatted with `.format` to get a string again.

Change:

```
const formattedDate = moment(new Date(date)).format('MMMM, DD YYYY');
```

To:

```
const formattedDate = moment(date,"MMM, DD YYYY").format("MMMM, DD YYYY");
```

Here you can find more details about the [string format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score 1):

npm install date-fns --save

import { format } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(), 'MMMM, DD YYYY')

[Check this document](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format)

Answer (score 0):

Moment is 150x slower than new Date . Please try it like this if you want to use this code working.

```
 getFormattedDate = async (date) => {
    const formattedDate = await moment(new Date(date)).format('MMMM,DD YYYY');
    return { date: formattedDate };
  }
```

you can read it here for more details
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/731

I would suggest avoid using moment because of the performance.
Use new Date () and then fetch the day , month and year and change into suitable format by joining the strings as you want. Use only Date library.